# Unity - генерация меша

Tags: unity3d, 3d

Создаю игру про фабрику. Мне нужно реализовать систему конвейеров. Сложность в том, что нужно как бы динамично строить меш конвейера от одной точки к другой(например: следуя за мышкой). Точки могут быть абсолютно в любом месте сцены. Например, это реализовано в игре Cities Skylines, с дорогами(кто не знает, найдите абсолютно любой ролик по этой игре, и посмотрите момент со строительством дорог), там мэш сохраняет свою правильность, и не выглядит уродливо, хотя может быть любой длины и под любым углом. Мой мэш сам по себе довольно сложный, создание алгоритмов процедурной генерации займёт очень много времени, и привлечёт тонну багов. Я мог бы по сетке расставлять мэш, как в factorio, но я отказался от любых сеток, тобишь мои обьекты ни к чему не привязываются, и свободно перемещаются в пространстве.

Я вообще не имею представления о том, в какую сторону двигаться. Выбрать ёсе таки процедурную генерацию или найти какие-то хитрости.
Приму любую полезную информацию. Может этот приём имеет какое-то своё название, по которому я смогу найти больше информации в гугле. Или у вас есть хоть какие-то идеи реализации этого. Пишите, буду благодарен.

Comment: Если умеешь генерировать меши, то сгенерировать линию из среза заданной формы и правильным UV, это не сложно. Я такое писал, имея слабые навыки программирования. Только проблемы рисования резких петель и пересечения как решать...

Comment: @Yaroslav, я долго думал насчёт процедурной генерации. Пока что решил просто упростить мэш, скрыть сложные детали под корпусом. Построить прямолинейный конвейер просто, а вот если вспомнить что его нужно изгибать под любым углом - начинает становиться страшно. К тому же хотелось бы его ещё и анимировать, а для этого нужны самописные аниматоры и прямые руки для работы с мэшем напрямую.